# How I can use socket.io and rxjava 2 android

Tags: android, socket.io, mvp, rx-android

I develop an app with mpv (mosby3) + socket.io.
I want to use rxjava 2 to relate provider and repository.

I have CategoryManager

```
public class CategoryManager {
    private List<Category> list = null;
    ...
}
```

If list not null i can do it

```
public Single<List<Category>> getList() {
    return Single.just(this.list);
}
```

But if I need load the list I have do it async like a it

```
socket.on("category", (data) -> {
    Type founderListType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Category>>() {}.getType();
    list = gson.fromJson(data[0].toString(), founderListType);
    // here i need to generate event to single subscriber
})
```

I think i should use to

```
public Single<List<Category>> getList(int count) {
    return Single.create(s -> {
        if (list == null) {
           socket.emit("category");
           // i need async load list
        } else {
           s.onSuccess(list.subList(0, count));
        }
    });
}
```

And CategoryPresenter should have code like

```
    disposable.add(session.getCategoryManager()
            .getList(5)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(data -> {
                if (isViewAttached()) {
                    getView().setData(data);
                }
            }, throwable -> {
                throwable.printStackTrace();
            })
    );
}
```

I think i can keep subscribers in class property

```
private List<SingleEmmiter> subscribers;
```

and remove subscribers in setCancellable method, but i don't think it good idea.

Help me please :)